# Máquina Ubuntu con Vagrant no levanta

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

Muy buenas

Estoy con Windows 10 usando Vagrant. Resulta que quiero disfrutar de una máquina virtual con Ubuntu. Cree el siguiente Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3002
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 3003
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 3004
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 3005

  config.vm.synced_folder "E:\\dev", "/workspace"

  config.vm.provision "file", source: "secure_mongo.js", destination: "./"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "secure_mysql.sh"

end
```

Cuando levanto la máquina con `vagrant up` muestra el siguiente mensaje

```
λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/focal64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/focal64' version '20220608.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/focal64' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> default: available! You currently have version '20220608.0.0'. The latest is version
==> default: '20220610.0.0'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu-v_default_1655215167623_38012
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 (guest) => 3000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3001 (guest) => 3001 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3002 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 27017 (guest) => 3003 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 3004 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 (guest) => 3005 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Me dice que tengo que aumentar el timeout, pero es que se queda indefinidamente esperando. Cuando hago `vagrant ssh` no hace absolutamente nada. Con Putty intenté conectarme pero no se puede. Si fuera en el momento de aprovisionamiento, por pantalla mostraría el error al levantarlo.

¿A alguien le ha pasado lo mismo?

Gracias y cuidense.